# I wrote a C programme but it's not working

Tags: c

Can you help me? The programme isnt working

```
FILE *doc;
char newriting[60]="Software Engineering Faculty";
char chr[60];

doc=fopen("C:\\Users\\MISAFIR\\Desktop\\trying.txt","w");
fputs(newriting,doc);
doc=fopen("C:\\Users\\MISAFIR\\Desktop\\trying.txt","r");

fgets(chr,10,doc);
puts(doc);

fclose(doc);

return 0;
```

}

//This programme isnt working

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: I'd say it's working perfectly, but your expectations are wrong. Seriously, you haven't explained what the code is supposed to do, or what is failing. Are we supposed to guess what your problem is?

Comment: Doesn't your compiler mention something when it sees this: `puts(doc);`?

Answer (score 1):

*"I see a lack of error checking disturbing." -Darth Vader*

##### Some Improvements

- Don't open two different location with single `FILE *`, without closing it.
- Must check whether `FILE *` is `NULL` or not.
- Must Use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`, when exiting the application, or use `return EXIT_FAILURE;` if something goes wrong.
- Must use `rb` and `wb` for reading and writing respectively
- Use `fread()` function to read and `fwrite()` to write data
- Initialize your variable `chr` with `{}`, if stored on stack memory
- If you are opening a file must use heap-allocation to store file's data of variable length
- `puts(doc);` is a big error, `puts()` is only for `const char *` (strings)

##### Final Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *doc = fopen("C:\\Users\\MISAFIR\\Desktop\\trying.txt", "wb");
    const char *newriting = "Software Engineering Faculty";
    if (!doc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not write file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (fwrite(newriting, sizeof(char), strlen(newriting), doc) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not write file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Data written successfully\n");
    fclose(doc);
    doc = fopen("C:\\Users\\MISAFIR\\Desktop\\trying.txt", "rb");
    if (!doc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fseek(doc, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t len = ftell(doc);
    fseek(doc, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *chr = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (fread(chr, sizeof(char), len, doc) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    puts(chr);
    free(chr);
    fclose(doc);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```